# What is a "hood" in this context?

Tags: meaning

A forum poster was giving an account of his visit to his friend who is an owner of a burger shack, and in one part he said:

> We smoked some of the Mr. Nice I brought along to give him and his employee for the trouble and blew it up into the hood in classic poverty restaurant style :coolface:.

What is a hood? Is that the ceiling of the restaurant? I was thinking this couldn't be the folding hood of the car.

Edit:

This is the picture of the kitchen he posted (couldn't scale it down unfortunately I'm on iPad :(), not sure if that device on the top left corner is the extractor or not, but could possibly be since I think there's what it looks like a fryer on the far right below it.

[image]

Comment: Was there an extractor hood in the 'shack'?

Comment: I read this the same way as @TrevorD -- a hood is a piece of kitchen equipment that's mounted several feet above the surface of a grill or stove top, to vent smoke and other gases from the grill out of the kitchen. http://www.google.com/images?q=kitchen+hood

Comment: @TrevorD I edited my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this context, sense 9 of *[hood](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hood#Noun)* applies:  “A metal covering that leads to a vent to suck away smoke or fumes”.

The “classic poverty restaurant” / burger shack will have a big heated stovetop, or grill, with a noisy fan to move smoke from grease burning on the grill – or in this case from the joints they smoked –  out of the restaurant.

Comment: jwpa, does a *hood* have a forced-air heating system? If not, how does it work?

Comment: 2) can *hood* be used as a verb in, as an instance, "Smoke is *hooded away*"?

Comment: @Carlo_R., typically a hood (and its fan, typically on the roof or wall outside the kitchen; see pictures at “[hood cleaning 101](http://www.power-clean.net/hood-cleaning-101.html)”) is part of a smoke and fumes venting system, and usually has no heating or cooling function as such. (It may *cause* some incidental heating or cooling, depending on whether hot air or cool flows into the kitchen through doors or windows to replace the air the hood moves out.) Re “Smoke is hooded away”, no. Verbs like *vented, drafted, moved, sucked, propelled, fanned* might apply.

Answer (score -5):

A hood is another word to refer to a poor neighborhood riddled with gangs and street drugs.
It is derived from the word "hoodlum", which was in turn derived from "hoodie", "hooded coat", etc.
In many cities, they refer to the prevalent poor and black community as "the Hood".

Comment: Um, no.  *Hood* derives from *neighborhood*, not from *hoodlum*.  And no one knows for sure where *hoodlum* comes from; it certainly doesn’t derive from *hoodie*, which is new street slang.

Comment: And while I’m not quite sure what the hood in this case refers to, the ‘neighbourhood’ meaning does not seem all that likely, since the poster on the forum appears to be talking about blowing _smoke_ up into it—I’m not sure how you’d do that to an entire neighbourhood, but it would require a lot of Mr. Nice Guy! (Who the hell smokes incense anyway?!)

Comment: As the dictionary tells us `African American Vernacular English, short for neighborhood` - however the question is related to a stove or [range hood](http://www.amazon.com/b?ie=UTF8&node=3741441). Pure coincidence that some hoodlums wear hoodies since it obscures their faces when they are up to no good in the neighbourhood